# How can I optimise my bogo sort?

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, sorting

I've created a bogo sort but want to optimise it. It randomly shuffles a string which has been split into single characters. However when it shuffles the characters it can repeat a random permutation more than once. For example if the word is cat it may try 'tac' or 'act' but then it could try 'tac' again. I want to code it so it only try's one permutation once, however I'm not sure how to do this. This is my code in python. Would it be possible to implement this?

```
import random

i=0
valid = False
while not(valid):
    word = input("Enter word to be mixed > ")
    if len(word) <= 1:
        ("not valid!")
    else:
        valid = True

wordlist = list(word)

resorted = False
while not (resorted):
    random.shuffle(wordlist)
    i += 1
    print ("attempts", i)
    print (wordlist)
    if list(word) == wordlist:        
        print ("Sorted!")
        break
```

Comment: I don't know python so I can't implement this for you. However, one easy solution that you can implement is to add each word to a list. Then when you find a new word, don't print it if it has already been added to the list.

Comment: I suspect this optimization isn't actually going to optimize anything. Checking if a random permutation is equal to the desired permutation is probably faster than checking if it's one of the (possibly many) permutations you've tried before. I'm also not really sure what the point of optimizing a bogosort is, since it's whole purpose is to be a terribly inefficient algorithm.

Comment: Does this really matter? Also to test if a random permutation has already occurred is probably more expensive than to check if the list is sorted. Instead, you could enumerate the permutations systematically so that each one is generated only once.

Answer (score 2):

> Would it be possible to implement this?

Yes, certainly. Other people already came up with a solution for that problem. You can use [Heap's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap's_algorithm) or the [Steinhaus-Johnson-Trotter Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm) instead of using `shuffle`. Both algorithms generate all possible *N* **!** permutations in exatcly *N* **!** steps.

This would also fix a hidden bug. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) of `random.shuffle(x)`:

> Note that even for small len(x), the total number of permutations of x
>   can quickly grow larger than the period of most random number
>   generators. This implies that **most permutations of a long sequence can
>   never be generated**. For example, a sequence of length 2080 is the
>   largest that can fit within the period of the Mersenne Twister random
>   number generator.

The bug probably won't occur in your use case, but it's good to fix it nevertheless (remember the y2k problem).

Comment: It's not that I'm not allowed to it's just that I generally don't edit other people's posts just because of one minor typo. :)

Comment: Im not familiar with the y2k problem

Comment: That's a problem of the past. A lot of developers assumed that their software would be old and forgotten before the year 2000 (= y2k), so they saved years as a two digit number: 19XX. However, in 1999 said software was still being used and could have lead to unexpected behaviour (people having a negative age and so on).

Answer (score 0):

For Python specifically there is the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module and [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) generates an iterator of all possible permutations. You can also see who such a function could be implemented there.

Just for fun: You could even just *simulate* bogo-sort with the following snippet:

```
import itertools
import random

word = input("Enter the word to be mixed >")
perms = list(itertools.permutations(word))

# This is the random part:
random.shuffle(perms)

print("Needed", perms.index(tuple(word)), "attempts.")
```

Comment: `itertools.permutations` returns an iterator, not the list you need to be using when you shuffle. I think you need to use `perms = list(itertools.permutations(word))`

Comment: @Blckknght You are right! Forgot to write that. Edited above.

Comment: Thanks for the help thats an interesting way of doing things shame there's a limit to the amount of characters you can do

Answer (score 0):

This approach will optimise bogo sort:

```
import itertools as itr
def BogoSort(lst):
    perms=list(itr.permutations(lst))
    idx=0
    while True:
        lst=perms[idx]
        for i in range(len(lst)-1):
            if lst[i]<lst[i+1]:
                continue
            else:
                break
        else:
            break
        idx+=1
    print("attempts:",idx+1)
    return lst
        
lst=[9,8,7,6,56,33,0]
print("Sorted Numbers:",*BogoSort(lst))
```